# market Beta in fama french (1992)

Tags: finance

i want to ask about the  variable "market beta" which exist in the Fama and French article "the cross-section of expected returns (1992) . beta it does mean the measure of risk which we know it in the asset pricing model? or it's another thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of FF as a generalization of CAPM. CAPM has Beta, FF has three Betas: $\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3$. But $\beta_1$, called the "market  beta" is exactly the same as the Beta in CAPM.